# How to subset only those data that show a positive slope

Tags: subset

I am trying to evaluate correlation between two variable but my raw data have a lot of background noise that I need to get rid of. In particular, I only want to keep the portion of the data that shows a positive slope. How do I get rid of everything else?

Answer (score 0):

I assume your data contains some outliers that are very different from the population of data points you are interested in and these are what you are referring to as "noise". Keeping in mind this assumption I would either:

a) Remove them from my data altogether, noting why (this might take some investigation).

b) Add a variable called soemthing like "Outlier" and give the outliers a value of 1 and the others a value of 0. You can then stratify your analysis or filter the data based on this variable. Again you need to note why you consider those you label as outliers not part of the main population of data points.